# Dynamic database for Django

Tags: django

I have a simple yet somehow complex pattern to put in place. I'm working on creating an app that will need to basically work as white labels for several customers.
Each customers should have their own database with their own information.
The idea would be for those customers to send a signature (token or such) within the requests or at connection, identifying them so that the app will know what database to get the information from.

I've read here and there that the settings should not be altered, but I was wondering how this can be achieved simply?

The need would be for a super admin to be able to create dynamically a new database and for a customer to be able to access an app with this specific database without having to redeploy the app entirely nor knowing beforehand the name of the database in the settings.

How one should achieve this?

Comment: Is it a constraint to use a new database every time? I would rather put all the data in the same database and call the data by user. If you are fine with this, I can write down the entire architecture of how this can be achieved

Comment: The idea is to separate as much as possible the data. It's a question of security mostly, a data from an app should never be accessed from another, so if the database were separated at least that would ensure this.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I have quickly put this together. If there is any loophole in this method, please lemme know (I too would learn).

Ideally, you can have multiple user_types to handle this scenario, an admin can handle all the data when required, and a user who can handle data related to his/her instances.

**models.py**

```
class UserModel(BaseUser):
   # fields related to user details that are not already present in BaseUser
   USER_TYPES = (
                  ("A","Admin"),
                  ("U","User"),
                )
   type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=USER_TYPES, default="U")

class AppModel(models.Model):
    # fields related to the model
    field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel)
```

In the views, we can check the AppModel instance user and the logged in user(that comes from the request).

**views.py**

```
def access_data(request, data_id):
    data = AppModel.objects.get(pk=data_id)
    if data.user == request.user:
        #do some thing with the data
    else:
        ## Forbidden request
        return redirect( "403-Error")
```

you can even write a [decorator](https://passingcuriosity.com/2009/writing-view-decorators-for-django/) for this (to check in multiple views)

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^access_data/(\d+)$', views.access_data, name='access_data'),
]
```

Please let me know if some more clarification is required, if there are any queries about the security.

**EDIT1**: added link to sites
Check this out: Django has [sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/) functionality. This could help you setting up separate settings/databases for each instance of a site.

Comment: That does not answer at all at my problem. My need is to have the data actually in separate databases, which is not the case here. I'm going to check the sites aspect but at first sight it does not seem to answer my problem either.